# display: inline-block extra margin

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I'm working with a few `div`s that are set to `display: inline-block` and have a set `height` and `width`. In the HTML, if there is a line break after each `div` there is an automatic 5px margin add to the right and bottom of the div.

Example:

```
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
```

Is there a property that I've overlooked that will allow me to reset the automatic margin?

**Update**

From what I've found there is no way to remove the margin... except if you either have everything on the same line or, add comments to comment out the line breaks. example:

```
<div>Some Text</div><!--
--><div>Some Text</div>
```

Not the best solution, but still easier to read if you have multiple lines.

Comment: Its not extra margin in any way. The blocks are treated as inline content and get word related CSS applied. word-spacing (each block is a word) and font-size is applied to white space between each block.

Comment: Some nice tricks which have not been mentioned: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: What's a good way to get rid of the bottom whitespace? If the inline-block divs are between two normal divs.

Comment: I cannot understand why this is programmed like that. It is obvious to me there shouldn't be any space between inline elements...

Comment: faced this task and my aproach this  margin:-1px -4px 0 -1px;

Answer (score 119, accepted):

The divs are treated as inline-elements. Just as a space or line-break between two spans would create a gap, it does between inline-blocks. You could either give them a negative margin or set `word-spacing: -1;` on the surrounding container.

Comment: wow.. I never even thought to give it negative spacing!

Comment: Setting word-spacing to 0 worked for me. The only frustrating thing is that word-spacing is inherited, so it has to be explicitly redefined for child elements.

Comment: In Safari, word-spacing: 0 fixes the spacing but word-spacing: -1em does not. Firefox is the opposite. I'd remove the whitespace between the elements in the html code if possible. Don't yet know what IE7 does...

Comment: The alternative is to use float:left on all the elements and set the container to overflow:auto to clear it

Comment: The word-spacing trick may work for fixing the _horizontal_ extra margin, but it does not fix (in any browser that i've tried) the _vertical_ margin between two inline-block elements that are on separate lines, one below the other. Is there a similar fix for that?

Comment: Here is an example using much of what was described in this question: https://gist.github.com/1819068

Comment: @matteo have a look at this jsfiddle to see a working examlpe of what you need. http://jsfiddle.net/QtDGJ/1/

Comment: +1 This answer helped me alot. I was scratching my head and smashing my keyboard against the wall=)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8226956/2122073

ul{
    letter-spacing  :-4px; /*Remove the letter spacing*/
}
li{
    display:inline-block;
    letter-spacing  :0px; /*Put back the letter spacing*/ 

}

Comment: I always use `font-size: 0` on the outer container then set the right font size on the target element - works like a charm.

Comment: Used margin-bottom: -1%; and it worked

Comment: `display: inline-flex;` might be another option worth trying.

Answer (score 133):

**White space affects inline elements**.

This should not come as a surprise. We see it every day with span, strong and other inline elements. Set the font size to zero to remove the extra margin.

```css
.container {
  font-size: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  word-spacing: 0px;
}

.container > div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 1em;
  word-spacing: 2em;
}
```

The example would then look like this.

```
<div class="container">
  <div>First</div>
  <div>Second</div>
</div>
```

A jsfiddle version of this. http://jsfiddle.net/QtDGJ/1/

Comment: Works very well. Note that if you're using `letter-spacing` or `word-spacing` you need to set them to `0` as well for this technique to work.

Comment: So true! But you only have to set them if you are not using a `em` value.

Comment: Setting `letter-spacing`, `word-spacing`, and `font-size` to `0` fixed the horizontal margin issue for me.

Comment: +1 - Tried Daniels solution and it worked fine in firefox, but not in safari or chrome, but setting the font-size to 0 did the trick in all three browsers.

Comment: this is the best solution

Comment: this one really solves my problem, thanks!

Comment: This one is the perfect answer

Answer (score 67):

A year later, stumbled across this question for a inline `LI` problem, but have found a great solution that may apply here.

http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/

`vertical-align:bottom` on all my `LI` elements fixed my "extra margin" problem in all browsers.

Comment: Found my own solution, a year later, but didn't work on my current issue.  Please note this is apparently specific to the problem.

Comment: Thanks! this resolves my specific problem with `p#myid { display: inline-block }`

Comment: I found that mozilla ff and chrome has different defaults or at least render it differently until you specify vertical-align.. so it's better always specify it explicitly.

Comment: Thank you! That is the only thing so far that helped me to solve that without ruining the flow!

Comment: This worked for my div elements too. Thank you, headache over!

Comment: Zerquix18 and Frubear - glad to help :)

Comment: Worked for me aswell in IE9, FF and Chrome

Comment: Works like a charm for vertical inline blocks.

Comment: this was a nice one! thanks!

Comment: i love you, we should meet someday :D

Answer (score 25):

`font-size: 0` to parent container

*(Source: https://twitter.com/garand/status/183253526313566208)*

Comment: this is genius...browser testing will tell

Comment: fyi: This works at least on Chrome, FF and Safari on OS X

Comment: this is the correct answer as the extra "margin" has to do with text properties

Comment: won't be useful if any text is involved.

Comment: @aderchox why? you can style the children back to font-size: initial;

Answer (score 10):

Cleaner way to remove those spaces is by using `float: left;` :

### [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MekEt/)

**HTML:**

```html
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
div {
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
}
```

I'ts supported in [all new browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=float). Never got it why back when IE ruled lot's of developers didn't make sue their site works well on firefox/chrome, but today, when [IE is down to 14.3 %](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp). anyways, didn't have many issues in IE-9 even thought it's not supported, for example the above demo works fine.

Comment: there are lots of other issues with floating and this question pertains to inline-block not an alternative solution

Comment: Back in '09 i would have agreed with you, but modern browsers do support this. just try and open the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MekEt/) and see for yourself.

Comment: you're still dealing with floats and going to have clearing issues. and this question is still not about floats. it's about inline-block

Comment: `inline-block` > `float`, for most cases, imo. Floats have nothing to do with modern browsers. Even IE6 (and older) handled floats fine. (Even if there are a bit fewer bugs now.)

Answer (score 7):

You can get a vertical space even though you have NO WHITESPACE whatsoever between your inline-block elements.

For me, this was caused by `line-height`. The simple fix was:

```css
div.container {
    line-height: 0;
}
div.container > * {
    line-height: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For the record, that margin and padding resetting didn't do the trick for me, but this quote from one of the comments above turned out to be crucial and solved the issue for me: "If i put the divs on the same line it margin disappears."

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of workarounds for this issue which involve word-spacing or font size but this article suggests removing the margin with a right margin of -4px;

http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/

Answer (score 1):

After struggling with this issue too many times I found a very elegant solution in HTML 5. In HTML 5 you should not close several (li,p,etc) tags; the ambition to become XML is forever gone. For example, the preferred way to do a list is:

```
<ul>
   <li>
       <a ...>...</a>
   <li>
       <a ...>...</a>
</ul>
```

Browsers MUST close the LI and they must do this without introducing whitespace, solving this problem. If you still have the XML mindset it feels wrong but once you get over that it saves many a nightmare. And this is not a hack since it relies on the wording of the HTML 5 spec. Better, since not closing tags is pervasive I expect no compatibility issues (not tested though). Bonus is that HTML formatters handle this well.

A little worked out example: http://cssdesk.com/Ls7fK

Comment: You are right. It works. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a link to the HTML in question?

Ultimately you should be able to do:

```
div {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

to remove the spacing. Is this just in one particular browser or all of them?

Comment: no link to it right now... but yeah, i have a reset(*) that sets margin and padding to 0. Seems to be a cross browser issue. Not one browser does it correctly.... If i put the divs on the same line it margin disappears. I can do it that way but i'm extremely anal about clean html! and... I sometimes use inline-block for my ul navigations and i can never get that margin to disappear. thanks;)

Comment: update... with all of them(8 divs 2 rows of 4) on the same line, the bottom margin is ignored.... its super strange. code looks like:

* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
div { margin: 0 10px 10px 0; }

<div>Some Text</div><div>Some Text</div>

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to this is to use an HTML minifier. This works best with a Grunt build process, where the HTML can be minified on the fly.

The extra linebreaks and whitespace are removed, which solves the margin problem neatly, and lets you write markup however you like in the IDE (no `</li><li>`).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem.
What caused it for me were a bunch of whitespaces (`&nbsp;`) that I inserted.
After removing them, the problem was solved.