# Can't get rid of spaces between inline-block elements

Tags: html, layout, css

Please see the following example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Gv6w3/

As you can see, it's a simple example of menu items set to `display:inline-block;` All I'm trying to do is get the menu items flush against each other- I have margins set to 0px, but i can't get rid of the spacing between them?  What is going on??

**EDIT**: Just noticed duplicates, my bad: [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements), [display: inline-block extra margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833734/display-inline-block-extra-margin)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

put the close tag of one and the open tag of the next element on the same line:

```
<div class="top-menu-item">
Item 2
</div><div class="top-menu-item">
Item 3</div>
```

Inline elements take the whitespace that is between them and this renders as 1 space. If you put the next element directly after the previous there will be no whitespace in between and the space will be gone.

Comment: @Bazzz- Good to know- but that's just too weird- going back to floats...

Comment: @Yarin, haha fair enough. Well it does make some sense though that inline elements are on the same line. It looks weird because they are `div`, perhaps if you used `span` and put them all on one line it would look less weird. But in the end, if `float` works for you, then why not? :)

Answer (score 8):

**Quick redux of the problem:**

`inline` and `inline-block` tell the browser to display an element as if it was a word. Words have spaces between them. Your options for getting rid of these spaces are:

1. Remove the spaces from the markup
2. Use floats instead, which don't care about spaces in markup
3. Or find the width of a space and use margins or positioning to remove the spaces visually.

**Solutions:**

All css options, forevermore: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

If you can't float, an em based negative margin gets my vote.