# How can I remove space between inline-block elements

Tags: html, css

I have this two `inline-block` div's with `width: 50%` each. And I need them to fit in one line.

```
<div class="inline">Left one</div>
<div class="inline">Right one</div>
```

I already know that this is a practical solution to my problem, but my code to look nice too.

```
<div class="inline">Left one</div><div class="inline">Right one</div>
```

Any good-looking solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Here is a JSFIDDLE demo: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/65adr/)

Comment: Do you mean to say that you want your code to look nice too? What doesn't look nice about what you have right now?

Comment: You could try floating them.

Comment: I don't want to end a div and start the following in the same line. This is a simple example, but it's less readable in reality (more divs in the same line, and lots of code inside them). I like good indentation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184512/cant-get-rid-of-spaces-between-inline-block-elements

Comment: @bažmegakapa Thanks, but I was hoping that in two years someone has found a better solution..

Comment: @JoaquínO The first one seems to be quite active, the last answer being posted a bit more than a week ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to apply:

```
margin:0; padding:0; float:left;
```

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/65adr/7/

---

Also check out this page for alternatives:

http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: This will avoid any space :)

Comment: Thx, I was trying to avoid floats anyway..

Comment: You are welcome. I suggest you to give a look to this page which is very explanatory http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score -2):

dont know what you want, as long as the second block of codes works why dont you use them?

Or you can use `float:left`

Comment: b/c I like to have good indentation in my code.. This is just an aesthetics issue.

Answer (score -2):

Add "float: left" to the class...

```
div.inline
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    outline: solid 1px #F00;
    float: left;
}
```