# Using Haml with the inline-block spacing gaps

Tags: css-float, haml, css

So I read the solutions regarding making the spacing go away when using inline-block as opposed to floats: [display: inline-block extra margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833734/display-inline-block-extra-margin) and http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/.

So if you're using haml and want to put the closing tag on the same line as the next opening tag, is there is a solution besides switching to ERB?

(and no, I don't want to mess with a css property of the parent container and have to override that in all the child elements).

This breaks (has spacing between the anchors).

So is it true that in spite of the recommendations to do such layouts using inline-block as opposed to floats, it seems that floats are still the way to go, especially when using haml?

CSS

```
nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  background: red;
}
```

HTML

```
<nav>
  <a href="#">One</a>
  <a href="#">Two</a>
  <a href="#">Three</a>
</nav>
```

Workaround (css-tricks one):

```
<ul>
  <li>
   one</li><li>
   two</li><li>
   three</li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li
  ><li>two</li
  ><li>three</li>
</ul>
```

another one:

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li><!--
  --><li>two</li><!--
  --><li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 15):

I found the answer: http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#whitespace_removal__and_

(this is a super useful article on the topic: http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/)

Here's a codepen to experiment: http://cdpn.io/Bjblr

[image]

[image]

[image]

And this worked:
[image]

[image]

Here's the html if the anchor text is on the same line (same result, but harder to read source html:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I had to switch from the link_to syntax to the haml anchor synax so I could add the whitespace killing '<'. Weird that killing the inner whitespace fixed the outer.