# rails form helper without break line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm using form tag helper in this way

```
f.label :something, "label"
f.select :something, options_for_select(...), etc.
```

But that generate something like this in html

label
   ....

What I need is that the form tag help prints without the break line

```
<label></label><select...
```

because I need that label select have display:inline-block and that creat inblock spacing gap...

I tried manually creating the label (I'm using haml) where the '>' fix the problem, but I don't know how to create the :for value.

```
%label{ :for => :something (??)}>
```

**update**

I didn't consider haml as a way to solved my problem, but it looks like in this case may work like this:

```
f.label :something, "label"
.divwrapper>
    f.select :something, options_for_select(...), etc.
```

this is a haml hack, I can style the .divwrapper including, keep the form rails form tag helps and with the ">" remove the whitespace around, but still bugging me that Ican't find a way to tell the rails helpers to remove the white space in case that I don't want to use haml for example

Answer (score 2):

You can add: `%label{ for: "something" } label`.

That will be rendered as: `<label for="something">label</label>`

**EDIT**

Follow this steps:

1. Use `= f.label :something, 'label'`
2. In the browser using a web inspector see the HTML rendered by 1.
3. Copy the value: `for="value`
4. Use that value in `%label{ for: "value" } label`

Comment: Hi @Cortex, I see what did there... :) but this is not the solution that I'm loooking for.... But also, I think that I'm start to understand that f is important as a context... I keep looking a bit more information

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for your problem?

```
f.label :something, "label", class: 'inline-block'
```

And in your CSS file

```
inline-block {
  display:inline-block
}
```

Comment: display inline-block is the problem... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612980/using-haml-with-the-inline-block-spacing-gaps

Comment: Gotcha, ok, my mistake, in that case, `%label{ for: "something"}>` that you suggested should work as long as you remove the symbol :something and replace it with a string 'something'

Comment: Hi, well, the thing is (and this is my mistake because I pretty in rails) that this :something is really something, because depends on the model. so I can't just put :something, because I need that this symbol to be the same as in f.label :something. You know what I mean