# jQuery clone() on a div positions it weirdly

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-clone

I have an empty div in body, with the following CSS:

```
div{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CcmFJ/1/

I then use jQuery to clone the element a few times. In the result, why is the original one taking up extra margin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually due to the white space being injected by the `.append()` method. You end up with this:

```
<body style="">
  <div></div>






<div></div>...
```

If you use `.after()` and insert the divs like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    $("div:first").after($("div:first").clone());
}
```

you get no extra white space before the clones. **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/CcmFJ/3/)**

Comment: But you do get whitespace between the rows of clones which does not exist in @moredemons fiddle.

Comment: @andyb - no you don't. Any spaces would appear after the last clone.

Comment: Yes, bad choice of the word _whitespace_ there. I meant that when comparing @moredemons fiddle to your fiddle that the result is visibly different and with this sort of layout I suspect that the OP would like no spacing between any sides of the boxes.

Answer (score 4):

That's the problem with `display: inline-block`. I usually fix this with `font-size: 0`.
http://jsfiddle.net/CcmFJ/2/

Answer (score 1):

It's the `display:inline-block` doing that. There are a few different ways to fix that, many covered on the question [display: inline-block extra margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833734/display-inline-block-extra-margin) already.

My preferred way is setting `font-size:0` on the container.

Comment: Rather conflicted here, It's a rather easy question, however you still came up with the first answer. Though @Moredemons provided the answer without a link first. and he does have a jsfiddle. hmmmmm.

Comment: Yes, editing the existing fiddle must have taken more time to answer. I saw no benefit in adding a link to a fiddle without also posting the code so opted for no code and no fiddle :-)

Comment: Hehe :) well I was watching when both your questions came in. His had the fiddle in the original post without editing. Eh not that it matters. He got the vote mostly because he has the right answer and only has 50 rep whereas you have... :P

Answer (score 0):

There are many many ways to fight those spaces between `inline-blocks`

The best resource with many examples is found under the following link: 
[**CSS-Tricks**](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

HTML-Examples without manipulating css would be (for example):

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li
  ><li>two</li
  ><li>three</li>
</ul>
```

or:

```
<ul>
  <li>
   one</li><li>
   two</li><li>
   three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Care to explain the reason why this was downrated?

Comment: Link only answers are bad http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143642/cant-link-only-answers-be-auto-deleted-instead-of-showing-up-in-the-review-queu

Comment: well if beefing it up with copied examples is better behaviour... thx for the info anyway...