# Evenly space divs with percentage width?

Tags: css, css-float

I'd like six percentage-width divs to be spaced evenly along a 100% width div, filling up the entire 100% width, but with a small margin between them.

Here is a JSFiddle showing the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/uQcGS/1/

Or code here:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner red">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="inner orange">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="inner yellow">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="inner green">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="inner blue">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="inner purple">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
div { 
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;  
}
.container { 
  width: 100%;
}
.inner { 
  width: 16%;  
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

Currently the margin is causing them to break across two lines.

I've found [some hacks for similar problems](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/RwU2N/1/), but I am not sure how to apply them to my specific issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Elements in the [`inline formatting context`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-formatting) will cause a small horizontal "margin" caused by spaces or carriage returns within your HTML. By removing the space, you'll remove the margins. There are some other [techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833734/display-inline-block-extra-margin) to overcome this behaviour as well, one of them is just using `float` instead

http://jsfiddle.net/uQcGS/9/

Comment: +1'd for the additional information and pointer to relevant W3C spec.

Comment: Thanks, but there's actually a bit more to the question (I've edited it to clarify). If you make the container narrow, like 100px or less, the divs break again - presumably because the margins take up more than 4% (100-(16*6)%) of the width.

Comment: Ah - changing the margin to 0.3% fixes that problem. Thanks!

Comment: when you shrink the page small enough, it still messes up though!

Answer (score 1):

You can put all `<div>`s in one line without any whitespace characters in between.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner red">&nbsp;</div><div class="inner orange">&nbsp;</div><div class="inner yellow">&nbsp;</div><div class="inner green">&nbsp;</div><div class="inner blue">&nbsp;</div><div class="inner purple">&nbsp;</div>
    <!-- Plus arbitrarily many more boxes... -->
</div>
```

Those whitespace characters cause and additional space between your `<div>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

Your margin, plus the width of the elements AND the whitespace between them totals more than 100% which is causing the break. Float them to remove the space, and adjust your calculations so that the total isn't greater than 100%.

Change your CSS to:

```
.inner {
    width: 14%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1%;
    float:left;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/uQcGS/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

i have update your code kindly check it **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ebram/uQcGS/10/)**

all you need to do is just 3 steps:

1. Remove `display: inline-block;` and use instead `float:left`(using float is better you just need to understand it good)
2. Decrese the width little bit(i suggest 16%) and use percentage in margin(i suggest 1%)
3. **Always** after using `float` don't forget to put div with style `clear:both`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
.inner {
    width: 15%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 2%;
    float:left;
}
.inner:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pulleasy/uQcGS/7/