# divide div with percentage

Tags: css, divide

Simple question I want to divide a div in to two columns I am using to divs with 
http://jsfiddle.net/petran/WnKW3/

```
display:inline-block
```

and it works fine , when I add widths with sum of 100% the second column appears
underneath seems that it doesn't feet on the parent window, if the widths sums
up to 99% is working my question is if that should always be the sum of columns ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because of the gap between the two child div elements in HTML code. you need to remove the gap between the two div's to which you are giving `display: inline-block`. Just remove it. It will work fine.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col1">
        col1
    </div><div class="col2">  <!-- removed whitespace -->
        col2
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WnKW3/4/)

For more information go through this [**link**](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

There are many other ways to fix this. which you can find **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1833734/1577396)**

Comment: But isn't it a better idea to float the DIVs, so you don't depend on whitespace from the markup?

Comment: @OneTrickPony ya that is other way around. but we don't know what OP exactly doing. as we can see just excerpt code from OP's project.

Comment: This is weird. How can a whitespace affect displaying of html elements.(Ofcourse, without a pre tag) ?

Comment: @Vivek , because inline-boxes behaves like words/letters .@One Trick Pony, floatting has sides effect and won't vertical-align those two if needed.

Comment: @GCyrillus ya you are right about the `vertical-align` which can be fixed by `vertcal-align: top`. (I know you know this, just informing to OneTrickPony)

Answer (score 2):

The white space between your divs take up space so your total width is greater than 100% thats why it wraps. Remove the space and you'll see

```
<div class="col1">
    col1
</div><div class="col2">
    col2
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WnKW3/1/