# CSS Inline-block Dimension Discrepancies

Tags: html, css

I've got the follow HTML code:

```
<section class="container">
    <div class="search"></div>
</section>
```

And these CSS rules:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, section, div {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body { height: 100%; }

.container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.search {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3em;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

If you inspect the `section` element, you'll see that it has 5px of size... I didn't establish the size. I leave that the browser calculates this automatically with the child's size.

**Why this behavior?**

Comment: Try to add `vertical-align: top` to `.search` element.

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6HaaP/)

Comment: @MaratTanalin I want to know why occurs this behavior =/ Not fix it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is because of the `inline-block` that you are using for the `container` and `search` elements. The idea is that `inline-block` treats the elements as text in a paragraph; that is `inline`. So while the elements themselves are `block` elements, the browser adds some space between the elements because of the whitespace you actually have in your `HTML.` Just like how adding spaces in a `p` tag puts spaces between words, adding whitespace between two `inline-block` elements put spaces between the elements.

That being said, there are a few ways to fix this:

1. **Minimize the HTML.** Possibly the simplest way. Instead of having white space in the code, just force everything to one line, like this: `<section class="container"><div class="search"></div></section>`. (Warning: this is untested.)
2. **Add negative margins**: This is a bit of a hack, but you can find out how much space is being added by using the inspect element powers of your browser, than make that your negative margin. That is, if there is 4px of space between your two elements, then apply the following: `margin:-4px;`. (By default, the browser will apply 4px of margin space between `inline-block` elements.) If you use em or a percentage, this could work with responsive designs.
3. **Use something else.** If you're trying to `vertical-align`, then `inline-block` is not always the way to go. Here's a good resource for that: http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/.

Comment: That's what I've been looking for! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it helped! By the way, I just tried your case in a JSFiddle. If you're looking for a quick fix, option 2 works best.

Comment: I'd avoid option 2 if possible, as it depends on font metrics, which may not be consistent across platforms.

Answer (score 3):

Here's more information about it.

http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

[display: inline-block extra margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833734/display-inline-block-extra-margin)