# How to float a span in a div?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to learn how to actually use CSS without the help of Bootstrap.

I have the following: (can be viewed here: http://plnkr.co/edit/FTCft1YOfQ4xy7FKWEHE?p=preview)

```
<div class="block">
  <span class="pull-left">George</span>
  <span class="pull-right">$23.20</span>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <span class="pull-left">Carl</span>
  <span class="pull-right">$4.81</span>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <span class="pull-left">Steve</span>
  <span class="pull-right">$0.34</span>
</div>
```

and the CSS...

```
.pull-left {
    float: left;
}

.pull-right {
    float: right;
}

.block {
    display: block; /* since, div, I don't need this right ?*/
    background-color: #87CEEB;
    width: 100%;
}
```

If I was using Bootstrap, I could achieve the desired effect, by putting my html in a `container` div and instead of using my custom class of `block`, add the class `btn` and `btn-block`.

I want to have the names align vertically on the left and the prices align vertically on the right. What am I missing?

Sort of like:

```
George                                     $23.20
Carl                                        $4.81
Steve                                       $0.34
```

Please don't mention tables, like I said, I could use bootstrap and wrap the above html in `div.container`, and then use `button.btn.btn-block` instead of my `div.block` to achieve the exact same effect. Thanks.

**Update 1:**

OK, I didn't expect there to be more than maybe one or two solutions, but there's quite a bit. Can someone explain the pros/cons of each solution? I'm really at a loss here.

**Solution #1:**

Add a [new div element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17938339/10333):

```
<div class="block">
  <span class="pull-left">George</span>
  <span class="pull-right">$23.20</span>
  <div style='clear:both'></div>
</div>
```

**Solution #2:**

Add `clear:both; overflow:auto;` to the `block` class by [thgaskel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2129835/thgaskell)

**Solution #3:**

This one seems to create margins between the blocks.

[Change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17938338/10333) `display:block` to `display:inline-block` for the `block` class.

**Solution #4:**

[Add](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17938377/10333) `float:left` to the `block` class.

**Solution #5:**

Discovered this one while messing around. Create a new selector:

```
.block:after {
  content: ":" /* <--- at a complete loss why this works */ 
}
```

**Solution #6:**

Discovered this one from reading [this page](http://www.css-101.org/articles/clearfix/latest-new-clearfix-so-far.php).

```
.block:after {
  content:"";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

I'm feeling pretty overwhelmed and am not sure which to pick. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `display: block;`, use the below css

```
.block {
display: inline-block;  //change like this
background-color: #87CEEB;
width: 100%;
}
```

**Update:** 
Since the gap is distrubing, better use

```
.block {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background-color: #87CEEB;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Actaully inline-block tends to leave space which can be prevented in many ways.

- [Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)
- [display inline-block extra margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833734/display-inline-block-extra-margin)

Even this solves your problem, check [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eJ2kY/)

Comment: But the `btn-block` in Bootstrap has a `display: block`?

Comment: This works, but I don't understand why this places a margin between the blocks whereas the other solutions don't?

Comment: @JPRichardson I dont think pros and cons in applying the css.  The only thing I would say, it should not affect other styles in your in html.

Answer (score 3):

You are close in your approach, the only thing you will need to do to make this work is to clear the float after it's been applied to the span's.

Have a look at how `clear` works in HTML/CSS : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp

Your html would look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="block">
      <span class="pull-left">George</span>
      <span class="pull-right">$23.20</span>
      <div style='clear:both'></div>
    </div>

  <div class="block">
    <span class="pull-left">Carl</span>
    <span class="pull-right">$4.81</span>
    <div style='clear:both'></div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <span class="pull-left">Steve</span>
    <span class="pull-right">$0.34</span>
    <div style='clear:both'></div>
  </div>


  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You could  also just apply `clear:both; overflow:auto;` to the `.block` class.

Comment: Jeeze, sooo many solutions that seem to work... I really don't know the pros/cons of each one.

Answer (score 2):

Add `float:left;` to `.block` class since its child are floating that why you need to float its parent div to get the full width

```
.block {
    display: block; /* since, div, I don't need this right ?*/
    background-color: #87CEEB;
    width: 100%;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: well you will see the difference after adding the tags.. :)