# Text align in span

Tags: html, css

Hello is there a simple way to align text inside span?
I found several solutions but nothing seems to work for me. Here is my code:

```
 <?php echo Yii::t('default','Tax Amount').': ';?>
          <span style="border-bottom: 1px solid; ">
            <?php echo Yii::app()->locale->numberFormatter->formatCurrency($taxamount, 'EUR');?>
        </span>
    </span>
```

All I want is to align the `$taxamount` to the right and leave Tax Amount to the left as is. I thought it was pretty easy at first but nothing works! I also tried it with div and it worked but it messes with anything I have below that. I have three more echo’s like this below that code. I'm not very proficient with CSS and I would appreciate any help.
My full code is something like this:

```
<?php echo Yii::t('default','Amount').': ';?>
    <span style="border-bottom: 1px solid;">
        <?php echo Yii::app()->locale->numberFormatter->formatCurrency($model->credit, 'EUR');?>
    </span>
<br>

        <?php echo Yii::t('default','Tax').': 23%';?>
<br>
<?php echo Yii::t('default','Tax Amount').': ';?>
      <span style="border-bottom: 1px solid; ">
        <?php echo Yii::app()->locale->numberFormatter->formatCurrency($taxamount, 'EUR');?>
    </span>
</span>
    <br>
<?php echo Yii::t('default','Total').': ';?>
    <span style="border-bottom: 1px solid;">
        <?php echo Yii::app()->locale->numberFormatter->formatCurrency($total, 'EUR');?>
    </span>
```

I comment out everything and I only used one solution as suggested below. 
So my code now is like this:

```
p>span {
display: inline-block;
width: 50%;
}
p>span:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}
.pull-left {
    float: left;
}

.pull-right {
    float: right;
}
<p><span>Tax Amount</span><span>EUR 12.50</span></p>
```

I use mpdf extension in Yii to print the results in pdf. So this is all my code now plus the mpdf extension.But still nothing happens!

Answer (score 2):

A `<span>` is an inline element, the text align will work, but you'll need to give the element a width (which won't work, while its an inline element).

There are a few ways to do it, one is to display them as inline blocks inside a paragraph:

```css
p>span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
p>span:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<p><span>Tax Amount</span><span>EUR 12.50</span></p>
```

Another way is to float them: (but I personally prefer the first method)

```css
p>span {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
p>span:last-child {
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<p><span>Tax Amount</span><span>EUR 12.50</span></p>
```

Comment: this works in jsfiddle. I had found a similar solution in other posts. But I doesn't work for me and I don't understand why. I comment out any other style I have and used your code but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If your left-aligned text is inside another element (like my `<div>` below), you should be able to add the `'float:right'` CSS style to your `<span>`.

```
<div>
     Left-hand text <span style="float:right">Right-hand text</span>
</div>
```

`float` is typically used for images, but it can be used with span tags.  It works by literally floating your `<span>` tag to the right edge of your containing element.

This should give you the behavior you're looking for, but you can also check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938303/how-to-float-a-span-in-a-div).  It looks like they're trying to accomplish something similar.

Comment: thanx for the help. I tried your solution and the link you shared. It works in jsfiddle but still nothing for me. Every solution I've found works in jsfiddle. But not for me. I don't understand why...It is getting really frustrating...