# inline-block how to remove gap

Tags: html, css

I want to to display two divs inline, one div is 25% and the other 75%, when I use:

```
display: inline-block;
```

It seems to generate gaps in between the two divs, which obviously knocks the 75% div down.

How do I remove the gap? I used:

```
vertical-align: top;
```

This has removed the top gap... Now just the side gap needs to go.

See here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/npP3p/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you have a white space between your two *div* elements, and because they are of *inline-block* display, it renders just like a space between two letters in a regular text.

The solution is using a negative [word-spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-spacing) on the container:

```
word-spacing: -1em;
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/npP3p/11/)

---

See more here: [Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Also here [display: inline-block extra margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833734/display-inline-block-extra-margin)

Comment: Great solution, concise answer as always.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the whitespace between your divs in the HTML.. Make it like this:

```
<div class="grid_one">

</div><div class="grid_two">

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/npP3p/1/

Or, use `float:left;`, but remember to clear the floating after that **or** give the container a `height`..

Answer (score 0):

Just add `float:left;` to first class.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/npP3p/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Tim is correct, its the whitespace that creates the margin.

Another solution to it is to add a `margin-right: -4px` to `.grid_one`, check [the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/npP3p/7/).

Answer (score -1):

Float left was the precious gem you were missing

```
Float:left;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/npP3p/2/

Answer (score -1):

Why not `float: left;` the divs?

Comment: If you're going to downvote, please provide a comment of clarification on why.

Comment: @Itay was that you again?! :)

Comment: I don't down vote working solutions :)

Comment: @Itay Haha, it's just nice to see a familiar face around here. I'm just playin', have a good one!

Comment: Just to make it clear, it's not my real face :)