# How to collapse margin of inline-block elements?

Tags: css, margin

As an overall solution to bottom margin of modules, I tried to just remove the bottom padding of my container module so that the bottom spacing will just be determined by the bottom margin of the elements inside it like so:

```
.module {
   padding: 20px 20px 1px;
}

.element-1,
p, ul, form { margin-bottom: 25px; }
```

It works if all my last elements (even nested ones) are block elements (their bottom margins collapse). However, if it so happens that within the nested elements, there is an inline-block element, the bottom margin doesn't collapse so it sort of adds up to the total bottom margin.

**See jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GHQrX/**

What is the solution to collapse margin of inline-block elements?

Comment: If you give any element display:inline-block it will add white space or line-break which create the gap. To overcome this issue you need to add negative margin to it. Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833734/display-inline-block-extra-margin

Comment: Isn't it because inline elements don't have margins?

Comment: If you remove margin-bottom: 20px from your class(.cont-3 ), it should work.

Comment: Why do you need an inline block element?

Comment: @BoltClock I am using it for buttons. They look like inline elements but they need bottom margins (hence inline-block).

Comment: @BoltClock inline-blocks also great to make responsive grids, but the incollapsible margin make it hard to layout properly