# how this margin comes

Tags: javascript, css

When I used semantic ui button, there is margin comes between button. But when I copied into my site that margin lost.

[image]

I added this **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QdYZw/)**

The `.ui.button` css are given below .. in it `margin: 0em;`

```
.ui.button {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  min-height: 1em;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  background-color: #EBEBEB;
  color: #808080;
  margin: 0em;
  padding: 0.8em 1.5em;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.2em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.2em;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0em -0.2rem 0em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0em -0.2rem 0em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  box-shadow: 0em -0.2rem 0em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease, background-color 0.25s ease, color 0.25s ease, background 0.25s ease, box-shadow 0.25s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease, background-color 0.25s ease, color 0.25s ease, background 0.25s ease, box-shadow 0.25s ease;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.25s ease, background-color 0.25s ease, color 0.25s ease, background 0.25s ease, box-shadow 0.25s ease;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.25s ease, background-color 0.25s ease, color 0.25s ease, background 0.25s ease, box-shadow 0.25s ease;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease, background-color 0.25s ease, color 0.25s ease, background 0.25s ease, box-shadow 0.25s ease;
}
```

But in my site there is no margin. I would like to `semantic-ui`  creates the margin ?

Comment: now I understood .. that is not a margin .. and its a `space` .. thanks for answers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how  `display: inline-block;` works. There are some workarounds you can find:

- http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/
- [display: inline-block extra margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833734/display-inline-block-extra-margin)

Answer (score 1):

having `display: inline-block;` will show margin 4 pixels by default so you can use `float: left` instead or use `margin-right: -4px;` if you want to use inline-block.

Or use `font-size: 0;` as @Mr.Alien commented.....

Comment: `margin-right: -4px;` is not a good practice, it will spoil the layout if browser font size is set higher than `16px`, consider using `font-size: 0;` on the parent element, and than set the font size again for the child elements

Answer (score 1):

It is just because you have written

```
<div class="positive ui button">Positive Button</div>
```

and

```
<div class="negative ui button">Negative Button</div>
```

on different lines.

If you write these on same line, extra space will not appear. i.e.

```
<div class="positive ui button">Positive Button</div><div class="negative ui button">Negative Button</div>
```

[Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/QdYZw/1/)

Comment: This happens because of the `white-space` and hence, writing all the `inline-block` elements in one line will help you get rid of the white space

Answer (score 1):

It's not a margin. It's a space. It's exactly the same as what makes each of the letters in this text separate.

To fix, simply remove the space between your two elements, like so:

```
<div class="positive ui button">Positive Button</div><div class="negative ui button">Negative Button</div>
```

[MAGIC!](http://jsfiddle.net/QdYZw/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to lose that empty space is to add:

```
.example {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

But be careful if you have some text inside.