# Why aren't these 4 divs next to each other? (width 25%)

Tags: css, html, width

could you please explain to me why these 4 divs are not staying next to each other? There are 4 divs, I set their width to 25% so they fill the whole page and yet 1 div is pushed under the others. I have to set the width to 24% to have them stand next to each other. How come? In my book 4x25% = 100%.

http://jsfiddle.net/cm2K6/

```
.four {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 25%;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "Enter" in HTML code is equal to a space, if you remove those spaces `</div><div>`, you'll lose the spaces between `inline-blocks` (or `inline` elements in general).

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cm2K6/3/

No need to go for `float:left;`, `box-sizing`, `word-spacing` or anything similair unless you want your code to look good.

Comment: This answer makes most sense.

Comment: I've been working on web apps for years now, and today is the first time i've realized this... Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

it's because `display: inline-block` has a natural spacing between elements. You can use `float: left` instead:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cm2K6/1/)

Comment: What do you mean by "natural spacing"? Is it browser defaults? http://jsfiddle.net/cm2K6/8/

Comment: yes, you can read more about this and some solutions here: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833734/display-inline-block-extra-margin)

Comment: @Morpheus Yes, that's the normal behavior of inline elements in inline flow. Just like when you put an image next to another one; or put a button beside a text input.

Comment: @Morpheus ditch the spaces in your html code to ditch the spaces in the output, see fiddle in my post

Comment: also a solution, however for people that use something like haml that would not be an option, but it's one to consider

Answer (score 2):

Inline and inline-block elements let a single significant whitespace character affect their layout
Remove any whitespace between the `</div>` and `<div>` tags

http://jsfiddle.net/cm2K6/7/

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to not let spaces in your HTML between divs. It's strange I know, but it works. You can use a `margin-right: -1%` if you still want to keep your inline-block, otherwise go for floating elements.

Comment: For this particular problem it does. I suggest you to read [this](http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/) go search for "The Whitespace Issue". Thanks

Comment: What @MrLister means is the spacing is not caused by the `display` attribute.

Comment: Also, the space is not 1%.

Comment: Ah Ok, sorry for this. I know that display attribute is not causing the space, that's not what I wanted to suggest. I will edit this. The space is not 1% but it's convenient.