# List item margin

Tags: css, html-lists

I have the following CSS

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

li {
    padding: 0px 10px;
    padding-top: 11px;
    min-height: 38px;
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    vertical-align:middle;
    cursor:pointer;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    _height: 38px;
}

li:hover {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .18);
}
```

But when I hover over the list items, there appears to be a gap between each item of 6 pixels as shown in the image. I know it is 6 pixels because if I add `margin-right: -6px;` then the gap disappears. I don't want that gap to be there in the first place, I don't mind using `margin-right: -6px;` but I'd rather not have to use this hack.

[image: 6 pixels gap]

My questions is as follow:
Is this normal behavior for list items, or am I missing something somewhere?

Regards
Crouz

Comment: Do you have a fiddle? This could be about HTML markup, sometimes whitespaces on HTML do that.

Comment: That feels like a whitespace issue, can you post a live link?

Comment: Maybe try setting margin:0 on your LI items?

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, you solved my problem and I learned something new today, can't ask for much more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the normal behavior of the `inline-block`. If you prefer using `inline-block` add `font-size:0` to the parent `ul`.

```
ul {
  font-size:0;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/z8Bxr/)

Answer (score 1):

Its because you have used `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left`. THis is how `inline-block` behaves, another solution is to get rid of the whitespace in between the `li` tags in your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your HTML, I can only assume that this issue is caused by a space (or a new line) between your `inline-block` `li` elements. The simplest way to remove this space would be to give your `ul` a `font-size` of 0, and set the `li` to have whatever your desired `font-size` is. This will effectively hide the space altogether.

```css
ul {
    font-size: 0;
}

li {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Ideally though I'd suggest you use a table layout instead:

```css
ul {
    display: table;
}

li {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but with inline-block I catch more browser versions, although I do agree with you and would prefer to use your approach.

Comment: @Crouzilles Not sure what browsers you're supporting, but table display even works on IE8: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table

Answer (score 1):

It's normal behaviour. See: [display: inline-block extra margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833734/display-inline-block-extra-margin)

My preferred solution is to use float:left