# Bootstrap center menu spacing between the buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to remove spaces beetwen buttons in this menu?

Here is my code: http://www.bootply.com/JUhVgyhThQ

I used

```
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
```

to

```
.menu_container 
.menu_container a
```

but here are still spacing between the buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's due to the divs being inline-blocks.  See this answer (or the whole question) for how to solve it:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8262649/609907

It's basically down to "word" spacing between inline blocks.  So if you set that to negative 1 or change font size on the parent menu container to 0 and back to normal on the divs themselves this will also fix the issue.

Personally I would set `font-size: 0` on `.mnenu_container` and `font-size: 14px` on `.menu_container div`

Comment: .menu_container 
font-size: 0;
Fixed problem. Thx!

Comment: Remember to set the `font-size` back to normal on the children or when you put text in it'll be invisible.  Also if this answer has solved your issue please accept it.